# Camera Filters in ios7

Tags: iphone, filter, camera, ios7, uiimagepickercontroller

How I can use the camera filters that already exist in iOS7?
If i used this code:

```
UIImagePickerController *picker= [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.allowsEditing = YES;
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```

the camera will open, and I can capture a photo but without using the filters.
my question is: can I use the exist filters in camera view in iOS7?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use CIFilters. More info about CIFilters can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/QuartzCoreFramework/Classes/CIFilter_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Or you could use the awesome framework that's called [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage).